# Updating GUI from another class which implements SerialPortEventListener (Java FX, FXML)

Tags: com, serial-port, javafx-8

I am making an application which uses serial communication. In `SerialEvent` method of that class, I am awaiting for a input from COM port, and then I want to pass it to the controller class of an `.fxml` screen.
Input will always be 8 bytes, and it works correctly inside that thread (I read the input and by printing it to the output, I see that the `String` is correct). However, when I try to pass it "in real time" to the controller class, I have a problem.

If I pass it directly, it does receieve it, but I can't invoke anything later (Not on FX Application Thread exception), I know that I can't do it that way, that I need to use `Platform.runLater` or similair solution, but if I use it that way, my controller class never receives that input, `textField` which I am trying to update stays blank.

I will copy part of the code here, and I am hoping that someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

**SERIALEVENT METHOD OF ANOTHER CLASS**

```
@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent spe) {

    if (spe.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            byte singleData = (byte) input.read();

            logText = new String(new byte[]{singleData});
            bytes.add(logText);
            if(bytes.size() == 8) {

                for (int i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i++) {
                    inputText += bytes.get(i);
                }

                if(inputText.length() == 8) {

                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            controller.getInputString(inputText);
                        }
                    });
                }                           

                bytes.clear();
                inputText = "";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logText = "Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")";
            controller.getInputString(logText);
        }
    }
}
```

**GETINPUT METHOD OF THE CONTROLLER CLASS**

```
@Override
public void getInputString(String input) {

    firstSerialNumberField.setText(input);
}
```

When using it this way, my `firstSerialNumberField` never gets that input.

---EDIT---

**SETCONTROLLER METHOD OF THE SERIALPORTLISTENER CLASS**

```
    public void setController(SerialController controller) {

        this.controller = controller;
}
```

**INITIALIZE SCREEN IN SCREEN HANDLER CLASS**

```
    serialCommunication = new SerialCommunication(this);

loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(path));
pane = loader.load(getClass().getResource(path).openStream());
serialController = (SerialController) loader.getController();
serialController.setScreenHandler(this);
serialController.setSerialCommunication(serialCommunication); 
serialCommunication.setController(serialController);
parent = loader.getRoot();
stage = new Stage();
stage.setScene(new Scene(parent));
stage.setTitle(title);
stage.setResizable(false);
stage.sizeToScene();
stage.centerOnScreen();
stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
stage.showAndWait();
```

Comment: How is your serial port listener getting the reference to the controller instance? You probably need to create a [MCVE] for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a reference to `inputText` to the (inappropriately-named) `getInputText()` method in the controller. `inputText` is presumably a field in the class implementing the port listener. However, as soon as you pass it, you then set it back to an empty string:

```
        if(inputText.length() == 8) {

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    controller.getInputString(inputText);
                }
            });
        }                           

        bytes.clear();
        inputText = "";
```

Since `inputText` is being accessed from multiple threads, there is no guarantee as to which order things will happen: whether `controller.getInputText(inputText)` will execute first, or whether `inputText = "";` will execute first. So you may end up setting the text field to an empty string.

What I think you intend to do is:

```
        if(inputText.length() == 8) {

            final String numberFieldText = inputText ;

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    controller.getInputString(numberFieldText);
                }
            });
        }
```

or more succinctly:

```
        if(inputText.length() == 8) {

            final String numberFieldText = inputText ;

            Platform.runLater(() -> controller.getInputString(numberFieldText));
        }
```